# IIS 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: networking, proxy, https, iis, reverse-proxy

I have a problem with a configuration on a IIS service, basically we get an 502 error when we want to establish an https connection. To be honest I am developer not a sysadmin but I am helping a colleage with this issue.

The following parameters are currently setted:

Server Name : XXX
Web Server : IIS ( Windows server 2012)
(HTTP) only for testing
FrontEnd - Angular  / Port 80
BackEnd  - Java     / Port 8787

(HTTPS) this is the goal configuration.
FrontEnd - Angular  / Port 443
BackEnd  - Java     / Port 9787

Only https://XXX:443/*  is available for endUser

So, in Dev environment there's no problem because all ports are available for everybody.
In production, the endusers only can access to one port.
Supposedly if we configure properly the proxy in IIS we can use it to call the backend.

The proxy works for  HTTP (port 80), but when for HTTPS(443) we have the error "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server"

### This is the web.config for HTPPS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
          <rewrite>
       <rules>
           <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="(.*)" />
               <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:9787/iam-b2e-backend/{R:1}/{R:1}" />
           </rule>
       </rules>
   </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

### For HTTP

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
       <rules>
           <rule name="ForwardProxy">
               <match url="(.*)" />
               <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8787/iam-b2e-backend/{R:1}" />
           </rule>
       </rules>
   </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```